# google analytics event tracking for individual users

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Hi am using google analytics ga.js to track a button click event. It is working fine. However, i want to track the button click event for individual users in my site.(eg. karthik - 5, Richard - 7 etc ) Am using wordpress. How to achieve this?

Comment: You don't. Identifying individual users is a violation of Googles Terms of Service.

Comment: Hi thank you. But i went through the following url http://davidsimpson.me/2013/10/17/identifying-your-users-in-google-analytics-while-complying-with-section-7-of-the-terms-of-service/        which suggests it is possible to track users.

Comment: Sort of. You can store a key in GA and match it against the same key tied to personal data in your customer relationship system. As long as Google cannot recognize the person behind that key (i.e. as long as the matching is done via an external system and no personal data is stored inside GA) you're safe. The typical wordpress user does not have a CRM, though, so I'm not sure this would work for you.

Comment: Hi Eike thank you. I have implemented google analytics code as in the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578410/tracking-internal-users-on-wordpress. Can you please tell where the report for this code is generated in Google analytics. Am new to google analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find a solution for this. I have used event tracking to achieve this. I have used the following function in the click event of the button.

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','button-category','Click','Clicked by the user:User id from my site ']);

In the label field i use the logged in user id from my site. Now, i can see the clicks of a particular user using his id under Behavior->Events->Pages->Your Page->Event Category->Event Action->Event Label. As username is personally identifiable info according to google, i didn't use username.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways track non PII user data using Google Analytics. This is an [example of importing CRM user data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user), which you could use import the type of information you are looking for.

Basically you can send in a User Scoped Custom Dimensions which represents a user with the hit data,and then import a CSV to map that dimension to any other user scoped custom dimension.